# Page Slide animation with CATransition

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, catransition

How can i set a page slide animation with CATransition. I have a UITextView inside a UIView. UITextView is a page. Both having 500 in width. The effect should be as, When we swipe left, the x value of the frame of TextView should change from 0 to -500. I can do it by UIView's animation properties. But here what i need is , when textview disappear to -500 (origin.x) simultaneously textview should appear from 500 to 0 (frame.x). How can i get it? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution myself. I used `CATrasition` with `kCATransitionPush` type as follows:

```
animation.type = kCATransitionPush;
```